# Is there any procedure saying "this function is not obtainable without using recursion at least n times"?

Tags: computability, recursion

It is known that $sum(x,y)=x+y$ is not obtainable from any compositions of basic functions $z,s,id^n_i$(zero, successor, projections) without using at least one recursion. also, $\times(x,y)=x\cdot y$ is not, without at least recursion twice.

I wonder if this can be extended to for any "at least $n$" cases. i.e., given any fucntion $f$, Is there a way testing this $f$ is not obtainable without using recursion at least $n$ times?

Comment: where $z$ is the zero function, $s$ the successor function, $id_i^n$ is used for embedding/projecting/duplicating and the number of recursions used in $f(x,sy)=g(f(x,y),x,y)$ is one plus the number of recursions used in $g$?

Comment: yes that's what I intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way.
Because you can build a recursive primitive function such that for some Turing Machine $M$

- $f(x,y)=0$ if $M$ does not halt in $x$ steps or less
- $f(x,y)=x+y$ if $M$ does halt in $x$ steps or less

Hence $f$ could use recursion at most $0$ times if $M$ does not halt or $2$ times if $M$ halts. But deciding if $M$ halts is not possible, so deciding how much recursions you need to compute $f$ is not decidable.

Comment: I appreciate it. thanks!